# mysqli_multi_query not working, nothing happens

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to do a `mysqli_multi_query`. For some reason it won`t work. 
Here is what i have done so far:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pw","db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

   $orderid = $_GET['orderid'];
   $sql = "INSERT INTO orders_archive SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."'";
   $sql .= "DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."'";


mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The `orderid` is given over by ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries must be separated with `;`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders_archive SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."';";
$sql .= "DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add semicolun at the end of the query to sepetare it

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO orders_archive SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."';";
 $sql .= "DELETE FROM orders WHERE orders_id='".$orderid."'";
```